# Why won't my simple loop run in jsfiddle.net?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Maybe I did not drink enough coffee this morning but I'm getting a strange error for this seemingly simple loop:

http://jsfiddle.net/za2Lrduo/1/

```
var a;
for(a = 1; a <= 100; a++){
    a = document.createElement('div');
    a.style.width = '10px';
    a.style.height = '10px';
    a.style.background = 'red';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

Comment: switch `a++; a <= 100` around to `a <= 100;a++; `

Comment: just a typo while transposing ... still no go ...  try it in the fiddle.

Comment: Ouch... People need to refresh the page before the click submit on their answers x)

Comment: `a` is the counter but you reassign it in the loop. Use a separate `var` for the loop

Answer (score 5):

You are re-assigning `a` as soon as you start your loop.

Don't re-use `a` for your element variable, use something else:

```
var elem;
for(var a = 1; a <= 100; a++){
    console.log(a);
    elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.style.width = '10px';
    elem.style.height = '10px';
    elem.style.background = 'red';
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/za2Lrduo/5/)

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting your counter variable with an element in your loop body. Go grab more coffee, quick !

After the first loop, a isn't a number, so a <= 100 returns false.

Answer (score 3):

You use the `a` variable for the loop counter **AND** for the div you create.
You indeed need more coffee and a day off. :P

Answer (score 3):

because you break a

```
var a,
    square;
for(a = 1; a <= 100; a++){
    console.log(a);
    square = document.createElement('div');
    square.style.width = '10px';
    square.style.height = '10px';
    square.style.background = 'red';
    document.body.appendChild(square);
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 3):

You are using the same variable name for both the counter and the div element.

Should instead be:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use different name for your variable for the loop and the variable inside the loop like this:

```
var a;
var i;
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    a = document.createElement('div');
    a.style.width = '10px';
    a.style.height = '10px';
    a.style.background = 'red';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the comments are correct, but the reason why the 100 divs are not getting displayed is because you are reassigning your `a` variable to the div.

use this code instead, `a` is now the div and the running variable is called `i`

```
var i;
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    console.log(a);
    var a = document.createElement('div');
    a.style.width = '10px';
    a.style.height = '10px';
    a.style.background = 'red';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

shouldnt it be

```
for (a = 1; a <= 100; a++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @JacquesMarais It wasn't initially; OP edited the question.